# What is the value of the $A$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

The sets $A$ and $B$ is sets of the same universal set. $A\cap B$ and $A\cup B$ is in order of $4$ and $128$.  $|A| = 2.|B|$ What is the value of $A$?

We know that

$$4 = 2^2$$
$$128 = 2^7$$

Which means

$$A \cap B = 2$$
$$A \cup B = 7$$

However, I'm so confused.

Comment: the cardinal of $A$ is $88$

Comment: Can someone take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your formulation correctly, then note:

$$|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$$

Plugging in what you know, we get:

$$128 = 2|B| + |B| - 4 \Rightarrow 3|B| = 132$$

And the size of $|A|$ follows easily.

Comment: Where did that $4$ come from?

Comment: @maxime You said $|A \cap B|$ is 4?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry ;)

Comment: Also, thanks for your great answer. I got everything.

Answer (score 1):

Highly confusing problem statement and deduction. The nomenclature for the sets and cardinalities are used interchangeably. Perhaps it is a good idea to separate the cardinalities from the sets themselves. Intersection or union of sets are in turn sets themselves and cannot be a cardinality/number (of elements in a set). So, the final question, what is the value of A is not right. It is just a set.

Further, the problem statement says, the union and intersection cardinalities (I am assuming) are 4 and 128. So, what exactly is the final deduction where you say, union is 7 and intersection is 2?

Comment: This is an (appropriate) comment, not an answer.

Comment: This is my first time here. Yes, it was a comment.